# @media query hides navigation on resize to mobile size but fails to show again when resizing back to desktop size

Tags: java, html, css

I am sorry if this exists, I have looked for it but perhaps I am not looking for the correct thing.

So in this simple example, I have a navigation that changes using @media query's, on the last query I hide a div called "nav-wrap" and chage it's look so that it is a little more mobile friendly, if you just resize the window down to mobile size and back to desktop size the navigation hides and re-appears just fine, however, the little red box at the top is going to be the mobile navigation access and uses a simple javascript function, when in the smallest mobile size and the "nam-wrap" is set to display: none, you can click this red button to show the menu and also hide it again with another click, if you press the red button to show the menu and then again to hide it, when I resize the window back to a desktop size, the navigation does not re-appear.

Please please any help here would be great as I have looked and I must be looking for the worng words as I have not found a solution.

Thank you all!! :)

Code Pen:
https://codepen.io/snave1324/pen/bGrNGXv

HTML

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Navigation Issue</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 

</head>

<body>

    <div class="header-wrap">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="mobile-nav" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-wrap" id="mobile-nav">
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="btn">Button</div>
            <div class="btn">Button</div>
            <div class="btn">Button</div>
            <div class="btn">Button</div>
            <div class="btn">Button</div>
            <div class="btn">Button</div>
            <div class="btn">Button</div>
            <div class="btn">Button</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById('mobile-nav');
            if (x.style.display === 'block') {
                x.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                x.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }

    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

html {

    height: 100%;

}

body {

    height: 100%;

    background-color: blue;

}

.header-wrap {

    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    /* background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.726); */

}

.header {

    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    padding: 0;

    display: grid;

}

.mobile-nav {

    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;

    background-color: red;

    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;

}

.nav-wrap {

    padding: 5px 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.726);

}

.nav {

    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1100px;

    display: grid;

    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, auto);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;

}

.btn {

    display: grid;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;

    border: 1px solid rgb(71, 71, 71);
    /* border-radius: 5px; */
    color: black;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;

    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;

}

.btn:hover {

    background-color: gray;

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {

    .nav {

        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);

    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {

    .nav {

        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);

    }

    .header-wrap {

        padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;

    }

    .nav-wrap {

        padding: 5px;

    }

    .main-wrap {

        padding: 0 5px;

    }

}



@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {

    .btn {

        border-left: 0;
        border-top: 0;
        border-right: 0;

        border-bottom: 3px dotted rgb(107, 107, 107);

        color: white;

    }

    .nav-wrap {

        background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.801);
        
        display: none;

    }

    .nav {

        column-gap: 20px;

    }

}
```

Comment: one easy way to fix this is having 2 navigations, one for desktop one for mobile, at a certain screen width you just switch the nav's around using mediaqueries. that way the `display: block` you set with javascript for the mobile nav won't affect the desktop nav atall, on top of that you could hide the mobile menu toggle completely for desktop as it is a bit odd to have when the menu is already showing

Answer (score 0):

The reason *why* the menu isn't reappearing is because you set the `display` style option to `none` with javascript which then won't be overridden by css code. The menu reappears in the desktop view if you click on the red button, because then the `display` style gets set to `block` once more. You can see this when you use inspect:

[image]

Even though `display: block;` is used, it gets overridden by the inline-style tag.

> inline styles override internal CSS, and internal CSS overrides external CSS files, and external CSS files override browser defaults.

To solve this, I would recommend doing what Ramon de Vries said in their comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to your requirement will be fulfilled. Put this code into your style.css file and then run it.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 550px) {
    .nav-wrap {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, using `!important` is bad practice and should be avoided if possible. Plus, this does not solve the problem since the nav-bar won't disappear on a button click.